# Drupal - how to hide headbar Menu in a page?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

my website is : https://www.edqm.eu/

I need to create a new page, but I want a page without headbar menu.

Is it possible ?

If Yes, How is it possible to do it ?

the website is built with Drupal 7.

I'm not expert in dev and in Drupal.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Administration menu ? or a simple nav menu ?

Answer (score 0):

it should be possible and depending on your site setup, it can be even pretty simple. You have to find the menu block in /admin/structure/blocks and go to configure on the block, there you should see visibility settings and you can filter out your page.
Hope this helps.

Comment: OK, I will see if it is possible by this way.

Answer (score 0):

Your header menu can be in:

1. Some block - just go to Structure -> Blocks from admin menu, find that block, click "Configure" link and in "Visibility settings" hide it by some criteria that is most suitable for your case (content type, page path..). If you have hard time finding which block is that use some inspection tool like Firebug or similar, to see block id. But if site is made well, when you are logged in as admin you'll have that "Configure" gear icon when hovering the block.
2. Menu can be part of some template file, most likely page template (`/sites/all/themes/your_theme/templates/page.tpl.php`). If that's the case then you can clone the template file and name the clone following the special naming convention so just the page you want to change will use that template. Then you can modify the clone and remove part that generates the menu. Check out this page for theming names suggestions: 
   https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/theming/template-theme-hook-suggestions

Comment: Thank you a lot. Your Method 1 works : http://dev.edqm.test.michaelcresci.com/?q=en/crisis-page-mc

I would try your Method 2 and create my own page template. But I'm  newbie with Drupal and I don't know well PHP. I have to find a video tutorial showing me exactly how to do it: duplicate and modify page/tpl.php and adding an access to this new template in Admin.
I you have an easy video tutorial to understand et to do it. :-)

Comment: Just copy the file, name it as suggested at that page I mentioned in the answer and clear the cache! Then you are free to edit duplicate as you wish. But tutorials are always useful, of course.